Is it possible to post an object to a Razor Page, from a form tag?
Is it possible to post an object to a Razor Page, from a Form tag?
Let's say I have this Page with the OnPost handler to generate PDF File
CsHtml:
@page "/generate-report"
@model GeneratePdfModel
@{
}

C#:
namespace MyApp
{
    public class GeneratePdfModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnPost(Data data)
        {
            // Do stuffs with data and return PDF File result
        }
    }
}

Then I have another page with the form below:
<form action="/generate-report" method="post">
    <!-- How to send a Data object -->
    <button type="submit">Export</button>
</form>

How can I post a Data object from the Form?

If you want to send an object in a form, you'll need to create form fields (fields that submit with a form POST) for the object properties. You can't POST a complex object itself.

In order to bind a Data object to the parameter of your OnPost method, you need to adhere to the naming conventions for the form fields. You haven't provided details of your Data object, the example assumes it has the following definition:
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

You need to ensure that the name attribute has the following structure:
[Name of object to be bound].[Name of property]
Accordingly, your form will look like this:
<form method="post" action="/generate-report">
    <input type="text" name="data.Name" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="data.Color" /><br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

You could use the input tag helper to ensure that the name attribute is rendered correctly.
More info: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding

Yeah, it works. Thanks.
